# matplotlib facecolor multiple colors all result black

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib

In order to plot severall load curves distinct from one another, function plot_loads is prepared to generate a random color at fill_between. Doesn't result as expected in different colors. Can't spot the error? Help, please.

```
def plot_loads(ti, tf, loads, max_y):
     """ 
     plot load curves

     \param ti : init t
     \param tf : final t
     \param loads : list of load curve lists
                   loads = [[ load1], [load2], ...]
     \param max_y : vertical limit."""

    #imports
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import random

    ys_array = []

    for item in loads:
        ys_array.append(item)

    y = np.row_stack(ys_array)  
    x = np.arange(ti, tf)

    y_stack = np.cumsum(y, axis=0)

    fig = plt.figure(random.randint(1,1000))
    #plot frame positioning
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211) 

    #plot maximum load
    ax1.fill_between(x, 0, max_y, alpha=0.1, facecolor = 'black')

    #
    for i, item in enumerate(loads):
        if i  == 0:
            ax1.fill_between( x, 0, y_stack[0,:], facecolor = random.choice(['g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k']))
        else:
            ax1.fill_between( x, y_stack[i-1,:], y_stack[i,:], facecolor =random.choice(['g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k']))

    plt.show()
```

Comment: It does plot different colors for me without issue. Can you expand on what the error actually is?

Comment: It does. Can you show me how you run the function? At plot run returns all black to me.

Comment: Something like: `loads = [np.linspace(0, 20, 10), np.linspace(0, 10, 10), np.linspace(0, 10, 10)]` then call as 
`plot_loads(0, 10, loads, 40)` which produced [this](http://imgur.com/YJsUxHM).

Comment: Finally realized there is no error. The problem was that was needed to zoom the figure or expand the window to see the color. Because the window wasn't enoughly expanded, the lines were too close and the load curves all look black. Many thanks.

Comment: @Jack Welcome to SO.  Please post an answer to your question explaining how you solved your problem, rather than editing the title.  Once the system will let you (I think 24hrs) you can accept your own answer.  Accepted answers is how SO marks questions as solved.

Comment: The problem was the edges of my plot were too tick. In spite of different colors set at the plot, when I look to the figure the display seem all black. Solved the problem doing linewidth = 0.0 .

Comment: In other words :    ax1.fill_between( x, 0, y_stack[0,:], facecolor = random.choice(['g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k']), linewidth = 0.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully figures bellow will illustrate the answer well.
Discard the 2nd subplot from your acquaintance.

1. Window not expanded yet.

[image]

2. Expand or zoom window, colors become visible.
   [image]
3. with instruction linewidth = 0.0 at fill_between, [SOLVED]

[image]